# Linking with static library not equivalent to linking with its objects

Tags: gcc, linker, embedded, static-libraries, static-linking

**Problem:**

The firmware image generated when linking with a static library is different to the firmware image generated when linking with the objects directly extracted from the static library.

Both firmware images link without error and load successfully onto the microcontroller.

The latter binary (linked with objects) executes successfully and as expected, while the former (linked to the static library) does not.

The only warnings during compilation are `unused-but-set-variable` in the manufacturer-supplied HAL, which due to various macro definitions are not necessary for the compiled implementation; and `unused-parameter` in various weak functions, also within the manufacturer-supplied HAL.

**Description:**

I am developing an embedded application for the STM32F407. Until now I have been working with one code base including the microprocessor's HAL & setup code, a driver for a specific peripheral, and an application utilizing the former two.

Since I wish to develop multiple applications using the same driver & HAL (both are complete and tested, so won't change often), I wish to compile & distribute the HAL and driver as a static library, which can then be linked with the application source.

The problem is that when linking the application and static library, the firmware image does not execute correctly on the microprocessor. When linking the application and the object files directly extracted from the static library, the firmware image executes as expected.

**Specifically:**

Created binary does not work when linking with static library using:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(APPOBJECTS) Library/libtest.a
```

Created binary works when linking with objects extracted from static library using:

```
@cd Library && $(AR) x libtest.a && cd ..
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(APPOBJECTS) Library/*.o
```

In both cases:

```
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(DEFS) -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -specs=nano.specs -nodefaultlibs
CFLAGS+= -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -mcpu=cortex-m4 -march=armv7e-m -mthumb
CFLAGS+= -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -MD -MP -MF $@.d

LDFLAGS = -T$(LDSCRIPT) -Wl,-static -Wl,-Map=$(@:.elf=.map),--cref -Wl,--gc-sections
```

I have compared the outputs of `-Wl,--print-gc-sections` as well as the `app.map` file, but enough is different between the two builds that no one thing jumps out as being wrong. I have also tried without `-Wl,--gc-sections`, to no avail.

The output of `arm-none-eabi-size` of the two firmware images is:

```
 text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
43464        76    8568   52108    cb8c workingapp.elf

 text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
17716        44    8568   26328    66d8 brokenapp.elf
```

A similar size discrepancy can be seen when compiling without `-Wl,--gc-sections`

Using `arm-none-eabi-gdb` to debug the microcontroller's execution, the faulty firmware image enters an infinite loop when the WWDG interrupt occurs. This interrupt is not enabled in the firmware and thus the interrupt handler defaults to the `Default_Handler` (an infinite loop). This interrupt does not occur when running the working firmware image.

**The WWDG interrupt occurring is actually a red herring, as described in the accepted answer**

--Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Summary:**

The issue was that not all objects from the static library were being included in the firmware image. This is solved by surrounding the static library with the `--whole-archive` and `--no-whole-archive` linker flags:

```
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(APPOBJECTS) -Wl,--whole-archive Library/libtest.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

The issue arises because if the linker includes a library object with weak symbol definitions, it considers these symbols defined, and no longer searches for their (strong) definitions. Hence the object with strong definitions may or may not be included, depending on search order and what other symbols it defines.

**Solution path:**

Using `arm-none-eabi-gdb` to debug, it appeared that the *disabled* WWDG interrupt was occurring and calling the `Default_Handler`. This turned out to be a red herring... which has occured often enough that it led me to the answer via the ["STM32 WWDG interrupt firing when not configured"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623885/stm32-wwdg-interrupt-firing-when-not-configured) stackoverflow post.

Upon reading this post and learning that the gdb function name reporting is often inaccurate for functions that share the same memory address, I checked the generated `.map` file for the faulty firmware image and confirmed that the `WWDG_IRQHandler` was located at the same memory address as the majority of IRQHandlers *including* the IRQHandlers for interrupts that are defined and used by the system (eg. some timer interrupts).

Furthermore, *all* interrupts defined in the `stm32f4xx_it.o` object (which defines the IRQHandlers for interrupts used by the system, and which is included in the static library) pointed to the memory address of the `Default_Handler`, and the respective IRQHandler symbols were listed as being supplied by `startup_stm32f407xx.o`.

I then checked which object files were actually linked into the firmware image (`perl -n -e '/libtest\.a\((.*?)\)/ && print "$1\n"' app.map | sort -u`) and found that only a subset of objects were linked.

Further inspection of `startup_stm32f407xx.s` showed that it defines many weak symbols, eg:

```
.weak TIM2_IRQHandler
```

During the process of linking a static library, the linker searches the library for undefined symbols and includes the first object it finds to define these symbols. It then removes the symbol from the undefined list, as well as any other undefined symbols that are defined by the included object.

My guess as to what happened is that the linker found an otherwise-undefined symbol in `startup_stm32f407xx.o` and included the object. It considered all IRQHandler symbols to be defined by the weak definitions therein. The object `stm32f4xx_it.o` was never included since it did not define any undefined symbols. This happened a number of times, with a number of different object files; sometimes the strong symbols were included, sometimes the weak symbols were included, depending on which object was searched first. Interesting (yet unsurprising) is that if the weak definition is removed, the object containing the strong definition is included, and *all* strong definitions from that file (correctly) override the already-included weak definitions.

Having solved the problem, I'm not sure where to go from here. Is this a linker bug?

Comment: Interesting. I never fell into that hole, but had similar issues with weak symbols using LTO (that's why I don't use it now). However, it stengthens my attidute not to use these libs. At least I know all code involved myself. However, for the interrupt handlers, I do much of the same: weak aliases to an endless loop in startup and the actual handlers being strong symbols. Could this problem be specific to using an archive (which includes the libraries) instead of a normal object file? Actually, I question the pros of archives anyway.

Comment: Regarding the wrong name gdb gives: when execution is stopped, a debugger only has the current instruction's address (PC register). So it has to lookup which symbol matches that address (or is nearest before that address in case of a function). If multiple symbols match, it might show all of them, but that would be worthless for most times, so gdb simply stopps on the first match. Which symbol that is depends on the lookup-algorithm (linear, hash-table, ..). This is a quite common problem for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a better answer if you can explain what "the binary doesn't work" really means.

**Are you getting a binary that your programming tools won't load into the chip at all?**

If so, look carefully at linker output on the command line.

**Are you producing something you can load into the chip and not seeing the expected behavior?**

If so, use a hardware debugger.  Step through the code until something breaks, or let it run, then halt it and see where you ended up.

Chances are, you're just uncovering a bug that's always been in the code by rearranging where everything goes in memory.  Array overflows, bad pointer dereferences, and uninitialized variables are typical culprits.  Switching on `-Wextra` and `-Wall` can help uncover this stuff.

One other thought:  Make sure you're LDSCRIPT has the correct flash & RAM sizes for the actual part number (i.e. is not for a different part in the family).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Brian; I have updated the question with more information.

I have also double checked the target of the linker script, which is not the issue here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I also work currently with that MCU. However, I avoid the ST "standard" library for good reasons.

It looks as if the watchdog has been enabled during startup and does expire soon (the interrupt is an early warning. This may be due to variations in run-time behaviour. This might very well vary depending on linkage due to trampolines created by the linker and/or tink-time optimization (LTO) and inlining by the compiler and other optimizations.

The sizes given seem to be out-of-bounds for normal variation with identical compile/link options. But they are very well possible for -Os vs. -O3 and LTO/no LTO (whereas for the latter the resulting code size may be very well larger or smaller, depending on -O). Also, I noticed some gcc/ld version have problems with LTO and all code has to be compiled&linked(!) with the same options. Also check the ABI used and that it matches the (C- and gcc-libs used.

A good start would be to coarse-step through startup from reset with a watchpoint at WWDG->CR. Also check the EWI-bit; this would actually allow the interrupt.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Olaf. It helped guide me to finding the solution. If I may ask, what HAL do you use for STM32 development?

Comment: @MikeHamer: None at all. I write my drivers myself and use my own framework. Not much more difficult than configuring and using the "HAL" stuff. Even more as this is not more of a "hardware abstraction layer" than a normal driver system. This is faster and better suits the project's needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `arm-none-eabi-ld` was not linking vectors table from startup file compiled as separate static library. I solved this issue by adding `ENTRY(Reset_Handler)` to my linker script so now linker was forced to grab some symbols from this static library (`Reset_Handler` function) and was linking vectors table too. This is elegant solution for me.